# Protesting Chillul Shabbat- מחאה

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot

Is there a halachic basis for those who loudly protest Chillul Shabbat publicly?
     I heard there are those who justify themselves by saying the Shulchan Aruch clearly states שצריך למחות when there is חילול שבת בפרהסיא.

Firstly, can anyone help me locate this source?

Secondly, if such a Halacha exists, what are the parameters of this Halacha? To what degree must people go out of their way to demonstrate and protest?

Thirdly, at what point does the מחאה- protest become a Chilul Hashem?

Comment: This doesn't seem different from the general issue of Hokheich Tokhiach.

Comment: A number of gedolei Torah have objected to stone throwing and violence as chillul Hashem.